# Insert Class on PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce

I try to insert style  on php but still not work, this my code so far

```
.'<strong>'.'first_name'  => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ).'<strong>'.,
'last_name'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_last_name', true ),
```

I want first name get bold

Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post full code snippet. Like how are you creating this HTML tags using php and how you are putting it to show on page.

Comment: Yes the whole story and not the partial code would be very beneficial to debugging the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not closed the `<strong>` tag. It should be '<`strong`>'.code.`</strong>`.

Answer (score 0):

Close the strong tag

```
.'<strong style="font-weight: 800;">'.'first_name'  => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ).'</strong>'.,
'last_name'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_last_name', true ),
```

Comment: soryy I forget close the strong tag but still not working dude

Answer (score 0):

Is your code an array key value pair with the `first_name` and `last_name` as key?

If it is then you should try this code.

```
'first_name'  => '<strong style="font-weight: 800;">'.get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ).'</strong>',
'last_name'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_last_name', true ),
```

Comment: not work dude
<?php foreach ( $get_addresses as $name => $title ) : ?>

Comment: Could you update your question and show us your whole code regarding this problem? @SandiTheresia